# Как сделать нумерацию объектов в массиве? JS[REACT]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

У меня есть массив, в котором создаются объекты у которых есть (id, text, boolean). И при каждом создании нового объекта, мне нужен его порядковый номер. (1.2.3.4.5...). Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочешь записать эти порядковые номера,т.е их индексы в массив,допустим,Нужно использовать один из методов.Возьмем map.
(название своего массива объектов).map(item, index) => {
return index
}
После этого создастся новый массив со всеми номерами,если хочешь более конкретные номера,тогда приписываешь после map filter и создаешь в нем условие фильтрации.Могу подробнее расписать ,если нужно.
На крайняк есть циклы,которые так же поработают с индексами твоих объектов в массиве

Comment: Мне не нужно их записывать в массив)!!!! Мне нужно взять индексы объектов из массива и вывести их на страницу пользователя. Где он сможет добавлять задания, а рядом с ними будет номер этих заданий .

Comment: Я просто не правильно задал вопрос.

Comment: ну в чем проблема.Ты просто из массива будешь брать эти индексы arr[] и записать туда,куда  тебе нужно

Comment: Я думаю с помощью цикла for это можно, но вообще голова не варит как это сделать.. :(

Comment: ты знаешь,как for работает?

Comment: просто с помощью метода намного удобнее,понятнее и быстрее

Comment: я могу подробнее объяснить ,если ты мало с ним знаком

Comment: Будь добр, спасибо.

Comment: пусть твой массив называется arr,запишем к нему метод map.                                            arr.map((it, tvoyindex) => console.log(tvoyindex) ) /*в новый массив запишутся индексы твоих объектов,аргументы можно назвать как угодно в мапе,но второй и будет индексом всегда.и вот в консоль будут выводиться все твои индексы поэтапно,но ты вместо консоли можешь указать конкретное место ,куда их нужно выводить

Answer (score 0):

Получить `arr.length` при добавлении записать значение в id

Comment: Логично, вот только arr.length у меня в компоненте (react), и если я добавляю каждый раз новый объект, получается его длина общая у всех..